# Please help identify

Tags: identification, houseplants, peperomia

I purchased this mini plant in GA over the weekend in a Pikes Nursery. It is only labeled as a *Peperomia* species pixie plant. I have looked ALL over the internet and cannot seem to identify this cutie.
It has very, very soft, velvety foliage with red coloring on the bottoms. It's so pretty and seems to move/bend towards light source fairly quickly.
Please help if you're able.

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: enter image description here][1]] | [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 1):

One of the favourite things for people in garden centres to do is keep the place tidy by picking up random plant labels from the floor and sticking them in random pots that need a label.

I think this one is an *Episcia*, but which species is a puzzle. Note that the plant is hairy; all Episcias are hairy and have the silver veining. *E. lilacina* leaves frequently have "often rose purple beneath" (Hortus III), but so does *E. cupreata* the regular Flame Violet. What leaves me in a little doubt is the pattern of veining which on this one appear to have veins coming from the base of the leaf, and minor veins branching from the mid rib. Most flame violet have one main vein but many branches.

The elongated stems indicate low light conditions so flowering might be difficult to achieve, but that would certainly be a great help in identification.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much for your detailed comments. I truly appreciate it and it is a major help to the identification! Thank you once again. Also, funny about plant shops labeling with random labels they've found, seems to be very accurate LOL.